# I working on a query that I want to run monthly that will look at effective dates as of 13 months ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I can only think of using the DateAdd function which is just giving me a 13 month range from March 2018 through today. So for March, I want it to return results for things that has an effective date in February 2018, in April I'll want things with effective dates in March 2018. Any idea or suggestions on how to achieve this? I think I can do this by declaring variables but thought there may have been another way that didn't involve declaring variables. TIA.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  As written, your question is quite incomplete.

Comment: I have a table with a list of drug reimbursement rates and their effective dates. What I'm wanting to see when I execute the query are the rates that has effective dates from 13 months ago. For example, if there are three drugs in the table with the following rates and effective dates; Drug 1, $15, 01/19/2018, Drug 2, $25, 02/12/2018, Drug 3, $55, 9/3/2018, and I'm executing the query in March of 2019. I'm wanting a query that will return only the information for Drug 2.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
Declare @tbl Table(
id INT ,
[group]  Varchar(50),
[index] varchar(50),
Dat DATETIME,
cases int,
closed int
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'g1','g2',GETUTCDATE()-1000,250,0)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'g2','g3',GETUTCDATE() -100,350,370)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'g3','g1',GETUTCDATE()-200,330,490)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'g3','g1',GETUTCDATE()+10,60,50)

SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE Dat BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-13,GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)
```

you get the 1st of the month 13 months ago.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  tablename
WHERE 
  datecolumn 
    BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0) AND GETDATE()
```